# How to draw in simple way Ellipse filled with a gray color and to set a Background?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I would like to draw a *Brain tumored phantom*.

To be simple : I would like to add to a background picture an ellipse filled with gray color.

I discovered the package Tikz :) btw I am so happy that there is stuff like that on TeX World.

here is what I succeeded to do until now , to draw a simple ellipse.

```
\documentclass[border=13pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [gray!60,fill=gray!60] (0,0) ellipse (1mm and 2mm); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

please, my question is how add the filled ellipse to the following picture : (I mean the ellipse on the first front and the brain on the background)

[image]

Will it fit to use \includegraphics instruction ? or better to focus on tikz environment ?

Comment: You want to fill the ellipse but put that as background? Wouldn't those two conflict with each other?

Comment: sorry I **updated** my question... I already succeeded to fill the ellipse with gray ... I want to to make the brain picture as Background and the ellipse as front ...

Comment: @Osryx, then ellipse will cover the brain picture.

Comment: ah you are right the ellipse is bigger dimension ... I will resize it it is supposed to cover 15% of the brain only @Zarko

Comment: now it is *millimeters* @Zarko check the code please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it adding an specific coordinate to your image using the `node` command and then drawing over it, for example, using this commands:

```
\documentclass[border=2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[scale=1]{brain.png}};
 \draw [black,fill=gray!20] (0,0) ellipse (2cm and 1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I got an image like this:

[image]

Comment: that's exactly what I want :D but your code is buggy ...?!

Comment: I add `\documentclass[border=13pt]{standalone}\usepackage{tikz}` and it worked ... thank you

Comment: I already edited to show you the full code I compiled.